# Top bar encapsulating logo and menu and using an automatically adjusted height

Tags: css, menubar

My questions is about the top horizontal bar encapsulating logo and menu. I do not want to specify its height because I prefer the browser automatically adjust it depending on user configuration (text size, disablement of CSS or image).

I have found a solution using `position: absolute;`: http://jsfiddle.net/5GmWp/30 
This solution also avoids the white gap around the black top bar.

```
#top{ color: white;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
      /* "absolute position" avoids a white gap around the #top black bar */
      position: absolute;
      /* Using absolute position, I do not have to specify the height */
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding-left: 3em; }
```

But this top horizontal bar is displayed on foreground, and the rest of the page is partially on its background. To fix that I have used `reset.css` to normalize the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/UKYrR/12

```
#top{ color: white;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
      /* reset.css removes the white gap around the #top box */
      /* position: absolute; // "absolute position" is not required */
      /* However I have to specify the height :( */
      height: 90px;
      /* If height=auto, the logo is partially outside the #top box */
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0.5em;
      padding-left: 3em; }
```

But now I have to specify the height to keep the logo image inside the black top box.

**What are the good practices to code a such horizontal top bar?** 
I would also appreciate good and tiny CSS tutorials ;)

**EDIT:**
Before I used to use `<table>` to fix this kind of issues. But I noticed most of the website use `<div>` and CSS instead. Another question: **Why most of the web site prefer to use `<div>` instead of `<table>` to display horizontal bar?** Is it in order to simplify the copy-paste from the website?

**More details:**
I am developing in my spare time a website to allow anybody create maps accessible to visually impaired people. Therefore I want the website to be well displayed in all possible configurations: CSS disabled, images disabled, big text size, old browser... But in the mean time, the site should also be eye-candy on recent browsers. And the CSS/HTML/JavaScript/images files should be small. And maybe no dependency on external CSS/JavaScript files. I will add the menu soon within the top horizontal bar. I am also re-writing the map editor webapp (SVG+JavaScript) but this is another story...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UKYrR/16/

That's so easy (and can be solved in such a big variety of ways) that I don't know what to explain. 
Please ask me about everything you want.

As for the `div` vs `table` war, there are even special terms like `table`-based or `inline-block`-based layouts. There is not the worst or best one here. They are just different *basement* paradigms of doing your work. I stick to `inline-block`s for more than half-a-year and have never seen something totally exciting in `table`-world that `inline-block`s or `float` or even `block`s (with JS) can't do. That's totally enough for me to prefer `inline-block`s.

Comment: Oops, I set `height=auto` and horizontal bar does not contain any more the logo and text: http://jsfiddle.net/UKYrR/15/. I am looking for a way to let the browser to compute itself the height... Thank you for comments about `div` vs `table`  war ;)

Comment: That's more like it now! Sorry, I've added a kind of advanced, `:after` element. It's just like writing another element in you HTML markup at the end of the `#top`, but faster. What it does is telling the `#top` how much height floated elements take. The link in answer is updated.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your tricky answer. I am happy waiting for about one hour for your answer ;) I have also just searched on the web comparison between `div` and `table`. I am now convinced to use `div` instead of `table`. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting! Feel free to add requirements to your task.

Comment: No worries. I will try to contact you next time. See you soon ;-)

Comment: Hi. I have found another way to solve my issue. See my answer below. The web page looks fine: http://www.lmap.org/ However I an unhappy about the position of the menu... I will see that later... Cheers

Comment: Cool! How do you want menu to be positioned?

Comment: Hi, I have just created a new room where we can chat: [CSS Logo Title/Description Menu](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30646/css-logo-title-menu). The issue with the current menu is when the window is resized => it goes under the description instead of keeping together... but I did not spend time to find any solution, I am coding SVG files and JavaScript... If you are available I can ask another question to give you more points ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to say I'm no designer but with a couple of tweaks I used your fiddle to create the following, it's a work in progress but I'm very happy with the look and feel: http://dexygen.com/LLC/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found a simplest solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5GmWp/32/

- added `body { margin: 0; }`
- removed `#top { position: absolute; }`

Result:

```
body { margin: 0; }

#top { color: white;
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444;
       height: auto;
       width: 100%;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       padding: 1em;
       padding-left: 3em; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @furikuretsu. I will test that on Opera ;) I worked on SVG+JavaScript (http://lmap.org/LittleEditor.svg) while I was waiting for you on the chat room [CSS Logo Title/Description Menu](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30646/css-logo-title-menu). I will no have time to work on this website week. Let me know what kind of question you would like I ask and when you will be available. Cheers ;)

Comment: Feel free to contact me by email at any time. I'll try to answer you when I will have free time :-)